# Drag file from VS Code to other apps will copy file path not the file itself

Tags: visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop

If I try to drag a file from VS code and drop it on another app (like: email, notepad++), it will copy the file location, but not the actual file.

I'm expecting to attach the file if I drop it on email composer, or open the file if I drop it on notepad++.

is there any setting to change that behavior?

Thanks